# dbpedia-owl:thumbnail image paths are broken

Tags: image, wikipedia, dbpedia

If you look at the information inside of DBPedia's film information, you will often see a thumbnail attribute for the film.

http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Matrix

which says there is a thumbnail (dbpedia-owl:thumbnail) located at:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/The_Matrix_Poster.jpg/200px-The_Matrix_Poster.jpg

If loaded, the image generates an error. Is there a correct path, or url schema that will properly load the thumbnail image?

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the Wikipedia article and follow some links, you'll find the image at

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c1/The_Matrix_Poster.jpg
```

although you can still retrieve it without the `https` at

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c1/The_Matrix_Poster.jpg
```

The result that you got from the SPARQL query was:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/The_Matrix_Poster.jpg/200px-The_Matrix_Poster.jpg
```

A `describe` query for that URL doesn't return anything, so DBpedia doesn't know anything about it.  Hopefully DBpedia will eventually be updated and provide the correct information, but until you might be able to get a working URL by doing some string manipulation  (e.g., replacing `commons/thumb` with `en` and `/200px-...jpg` by an empty string).  I don't know how portable that would be, though.

Comment: I, too, considered doing this. Though, I've looked around, and there are several movie thumbnails in wikipedia and on dbpedia that do not have the same url structure as this, so I have the impression that its not uniform, and thus a string manipulation solution may be short-lived